# Importar dados do banco central para o R

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber se é possível e como importar dados do banco central direto para o R
Se existe alguma api ou pacote específico para acessar as séries temporais

Answer (score 5):

O pacote [`rbcb`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbcb/index.html). O título do pacote é **R Interface to Brazilian Central Bank Web Services**. Você pode obter mais detalhes no [github](https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/rbcb) do criador.